# Symfony 4 EntityType database not updated

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have an issue with EntityType form field.

Entity "Freelancer" is in relation ManyToMany with entity "Sapsubdomain".
In Form on FreelancerType I added "sapsubdomains" as EntityType.

When I save my form all fields are saved correctly to database exepting "sapsubdomains".

I expect to have relation table between "Freelancer" and "Sapsubdomain" updated but nothing happen. I have no error message ...

Thanks for your help !

"Freelancer" Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FreelancerRepository")
 */
class Freelancer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $about;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $Userid;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sapsubdomain", mappedBy="freelancer")
     */
    private $sapsubdomains;

    public function __construct()
  {
    $this->sapsubdomains = new ArrayCollection();
  }


    /**
     * @return Collection|Sapsubdomain[]
     */
    public function getSapsubdomains(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sapsubdomains;
    }

    public function addSapsubdomain(Sapsubdomain $sapsubdomain): self
    {
        if (!$this->sapsubdomains->contains($sapsubdomain)) {
            $this->sapsubdomains[] = $sapsubdomain;
            $sapsubdomain->addFreelancer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSapsubdomain(Sapsubdomain $sapsubdomain): self
    {
        if ($this->sapsubdomains->contains($sapsubdomain)) {
            $this->sapsubdomains->removeElement($sapsubdomain);
            $sapsubdomain->removeFreelancer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }




}
```

"Sapsubdomain" Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SapsubdomainRepository")
 */
class Sapsubdomain
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subdomain;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sapdomain", inversedBy="sapsubdomains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $domain;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\freelancer", inversedBy="sapsubdomains")
     */
    private $freelancer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->freelancer = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSubdomain(): ?string
    {
        return $this->subdomain;
    }

    public function setSubdomain(?string $subdomain): self
    {
        $this->subdomain = $subdomain;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomain(): ?sapdomain
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function setDomain(?sapdomain $domain): self
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|freelancer[]
     */
    public function getFreelancer(): Collection
    {
        return $this->freelancer;
    }

    public function addFreelancer(freelancer $freelancer): self
    {
        if (!$this->freelancer->contains($freelancer)) {
            $this->freelancer[] = $freelancer;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFreelancer(freelancer $freelancer): self
    {
        if ($this->freelancer->contains($freelancer)) {
            $this->freelancer->removeElement($freelancer);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Form FreelancerType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;


class FreelancerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('sapsubdomains', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Sapsubdomain::class,
                'choice_label' => 'subdomain',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                 ))
```

FreelancerController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

/**
* @Route("/freelancer", name="freelancer")
* @Security("is_granted('ROLE_FREELANCER')")
*/
class FreelancerController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/settings/", name="freelancer_settings")
    */
    public function modifyfreelancesettings(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        //On récupére l'utilisateur
        $user = $this->getUser();

        //On recherche le profil freelance du user
        $freelancer = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Freelancer::class)
        ->findOneBy(array('Userid'=>$user));

        // Si le profil freelance n'existe pas pour le user on appel la fonction de création du profil
        if (!$freelancer) {
            $this->createfreelancesettings($request);
        }

        //Sinon on met à jour le profil du freelance
        $form = $this->createForm(FreelancerType::class, $freelancer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //On des données du freelance pour éventuellement les envoyer à TWIG
        $tjm = $form->get('dailyrate')->getData();
        $curr = $form->get('ratecurrency')->getData();

        // On vérifie que le formulaire est soumis

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $freelancer->setUpdateDate(new \DateTime('now'));


            /** @var UploadedFile $pictureFile */
            $pictureFile  = $form['picture']->getData();

                if ($pictureFile ) {
                    $pictureFileName  = $fileUploader->upload($pictureFile);
                    $freelancer->setProfilePicture($pictureFileName);
                }

            //Mise à jour des relations
            $sapsubdomains  = $form['sapsubdomains']->getData();    

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em -> flush();

            $this->addFlash('notice',
                        'Your SAP Profile has been saved !'
                        );

                            return $this->redirect($request->getUri());


        }

        return $this->render('freelancer/settings.html.twig', array(
            'picture' => $freelancer,
            'curr' => $curr,
            'freelancer'=> $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
```

In the template for this field I have only:

```
{{ form_widget(freelancer.sapsubdomains) }}
```

EDIT: I added this to the controller:

```
$subdomaintexts  = $form['sapsubdomains']->getData();

            $sapsubdomains = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Sapsubdomain::class)
            ->findBy(array('subdomain'=>$subdomaintexts));

            $freelancer->addSapsubdomain($sapsubdomains);
```

But now I have this error message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
>   t0.subdomain AS subdomain_2, t0.domain_id AS domain_id_3 FROM
>   sapsubdomain t0 WHERE t0.subdomain = ?' with params [{}]:
>
> Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be
>   converted to string

Comment: could you show both the controller code and the template where this is rendered? the form itself and the entity look fine afaict.

Comment: I updated my message with controller and template.

Comment: `$form['sapsubdomains']` should contain *entities* and not just the labels you chose to display. it also fetches the list in there from the freelancer entity, that's why it's a PersistentCollection (Which obviously can't be converted to a string, which your query implies it to be). That being said, aside from your added code it should work, and I don't see why it doesn't. is it possible that the relation is added? how do you check? use `dump($form['sapsubdomains']->getData())` to see if the form sets the entities correctly (inside the `if( ... $form->isValid()) { // here }`. -> check profiler!

Comment: `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   dump($form['sapsubdomains']->getData());` There is no error in profiler but relation table sapsubdomain_freelancer is still empty.

Comment: there shouldn't be an error, but you should look if the debug section in the profiler contains the entities you selected.

Comment: In dubug section I have `-sapsubdomains: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#762}` I don't understand everything but I can drill down until `sapsubdomains` that has been fullfil in the fom: `-subdomain: "SAP General Ledger Accounting (FI-GL)"`

Comment: okay, so usually, relations should get updated in the database alongside the entity. and if I understand you correctly, the sapsubdomains are actually set on the entity before the entitymanager's flush call. can you try `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` on the console and see if anything pops up?

Comment: no error in consol:  Mapping `[OK] The mapping files are correct.` Database  `[OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files. `

Comment: I'm honestly out of ideas, sry.

Comment: Thank you for trying :) Can it be a question of the owning side ? If yes how can I know which entity has the owning ?

Comment: the owning side is the one, where the "inversed" is in the annotation. but that should be okay afaict. since you always also add the freelancer to the sapsubdomain as well

Comment: One point : I added entries of sapsubdomain directly in the database (phpmyadmin). Maybe I need to update all the data in the database only throw Doctrine ?

Comment: doctrine doesn't care, it builds its entities from the database (especially on dev, there's no cache kept between requests, unless you have some weird config for doctrine, but you would have had to done that yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted entities and re make them. Everything works now. Really wierd...

Comment: In your controller, you are not calling `$em->persist()` on any of the entities.

Comment: @ehymel since it's all existing entities that shouldn't be a problem (all of them loaded from the entity manager) would require a non-default change management policy in doctrine to matter. flush is called, that should be sufficient. I looked for that too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to save collection of `Sapsubdomain` to your `Freelancer` type Entity.
Right way to embed collections to forms is to use `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType::class` so that symfony process the colelction properly.

```
<?php

class FreelancerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /** Other Fields **/

        $builder->add('sapsubdomains', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => SapsubdomainType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
             /** Other Options **/
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Freelancer::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Whole example code is found at Symfony Docs : [Using Form Collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)